# error: Object 'output' not found

Tags: r, shiny

[Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Jg_Z2eVkOXc2k2Y1lDVHdpOFk)

getting error:

```
output object not found
```

don't know why this is happening ,i have done the same stuff on past dashboard that time no error occurred.
Output object is specified ,but still it cant detect

**Server.R**

```
d <-read_excel("data/ds.xlsx",sheet = 1)
output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
data <- switch(input$var, 
           "Beginning Stocks (1000 MT)"= d$`Beginning Stocks (1000 MT)`
           ,"Area Harvested (1000 HA)" = d$`Area Harvested (1000 HA)`
           ,"Yield (MT/HA)" = d$`Yield (MT/HA)`
           ,"Production (1000 MT)" = d$`Production (1000 MT)`
           ,"MY Imports (1000 MT)" =d$`MY Imports (1000 MT)`

        )
   data1 <- switch(input$var1,
                 "Beginning Stocks (1000 MT)"= d$`Beginning Stocks (1000 
                 MT)`
              ,"Area Harvested (1000 HA)" = d$`Area Harvested (1000 HA)`
              ,"Yield (MT/HA)" = d$`Yield (MT/HA)`
              ,"Production (1000 MT)" = d$`Production (1000 MT)`
              ,"MY Imports (1000 MT)" =d$`MY Imports (1000 MT)`
                          )
      plot_ly(d, x =~d$`Attributes (Unit)`, y = ~data,type= "scatter",mode = 
      'markers+lines',  marker = list(size = 10),name=input$var) %>%
      add_trace(x = ~d$`Attributes (Unit)`, y = ~data1,type="scatter"
      ,mode="markers+lines",name=input$var1)
         })
```

**UI.R**

```
   navbarPage("Barley Dashboard", 
       tabPanel("Balance sheet",
                fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
          mainPanel(fluidRow( column(8,selectInput("var",selected="select",
          label = "Choose first variable",                                        
         choices = c( "Beginning Stocks (1000 MT)","Area Harvested (1000 
         HA)","Yield (MT/HA)","Production (1000 MT)","MY Imports (1000 
         MT)")
                            )
                            ),
        column(8,selectInput("var1", selected = "select",
         label = "Choose second variable",choices = c("Beginning Stocks 
         (1000 MT)", "Area Harvested (1000 HA)","Yield (MT/HA)","Production 
           (1000 MT)","MY Imports (1000 MT)")
                            )
                            )
                            ),
           plotlyOutput("plot1")
         ) ) ) )
```

getting error :`Error in output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({ : object 'output' not found`

I am not able to rectify the error

Comment: Do u have `server <- function(input, output, session){`

Comment: @akrun no i created separate tabs for ui and server ,so not included this

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, so others can't try it on their machine

Comment: I have reproduced the example. The problem now is that you didn't initiale your `d` dataframe anywhere... So there's still error from that

Comment: now i have added the data ,can you try it now @AntoinePissoort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced your example in a single file `app.R` inside a folder named "app". Do not forget to load the relevant packages with `library`! Also, don't break lines in `selectInput` choices because this will be used for the column names.

The things you are doing with the `switch()`'s can be directly handled through Shiny by retrieving the input column's names from `d`  in `plot_ly()`.

Finally, do not forget to import your dataset (`d`) in your script.

```
library(shinythemes)
library(plotly)

ui <- navbarPage("Barley Dashboard", 
           tabPanel("Balance sheet",
                    fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
                              mainPanel(fluidRow( 
                                column(8,
                                       selectInput("var",
                                                   selected="select",
                                                   label = "Choose first variable",                      
                                                   choices = c( "Beginning Stocks (1000 MT)",
                                                                "Area Harvested (1000 HA)","Yield (MT/HA)",
                                                                "Production (1000 MT)","MY Imports (1000 MT)"))
                              ),
                              column(8,selectInput("var1", selected = "select",
                                                   label = "Choose second variable",
                                                   choices = c("Beginning Stocks (1000 MT)",
                                                               "Area Harvested (1000 HA)","Yield (MT/HA)",
                                                               "Production (1000 MT)","MY Imports (1000 MT)")))
                              ),
                              plotlyOutput("plot1")
                              ) ) 
                    ) )

library("openxlsx")
d <- read.xlsx("ds.xlsx", check.names = F)
# Handle the changes of the colnames with dots instead of spaces due to read.xlsx()
names(d) <- gsub(x = names(d), pattern = "\\.", replacement = " ")

'server' <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
  #browser()
  plot_ly(d, x =~d$`Attributes (Unit)`, y = ~d[,input$var],
          type= "scatter",mode = 'markers+lines',  
          marker = list(size = 10),name=input$var) %>%
    add_trace(x = ~d$`Attributes (Unit)`, y = ~d[,input$var1],type="scatter",
              mode="markers+lines", name=input$var1,yaxis="y2")
})
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Although I don't think this is the output you expected from `add_trace()` in your `plot_ly` code.

Comment: can you help me in adding the trace in plotly @Antoine Pissoort